# How to to run separate processes on iOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, nstask

How can I run a separate process (the executable will be in the main bundle) on iOS? NSTask seems to be missing...

BTW I don't care if this will be rejected by Apple, as it will never be submitted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to run a seperate process other than launching a process that can run in background from xcode or the home screen.

If you want process 1 to kick off process 2 then you're out of luck.

However, if you want process 1 to run in background and then process 2 to be launched later and communicate with process 1 (via memory-mapped files or network) then you can do that as xcode will allow you to run more than one application on the simulator at a time.

Alternatively, you can emulate a process via a thread but that depends on what you want to do.

Comment: No I mean you can press RUN from Xcode and run your program on an iOS device.  Xcode DOES run programs, and debugs them and edits them.  If you want to be pedantic, we can say the ARM CPU runs the programs, not the OS.